# When representing a sparse graph with an adjacency matrix, why use linked list as structure to contain edges?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, linked-list

When representing graphs in memory in a language like Java, either an adjacency matrix is used (for dense graphs) or an adjacency list for sparse graphs.

So say we represent the latter like

```
Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> graph;
```

The integer key represents the vertex and LinkedList contains all the other vertexes it points to.

Why use a LinkedList to represent the edges? Couldn't an int[] or ArrayList work just as fine, or is there a reason why you want to represent the edges in a way that maintains the ordering such as

```
2 -> 4 -> 1 -> 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either an `int[]` or `ArrayList` could also work.

I wouldn't recommend an `int[]` right off the bat though, as you'll need to cater for resizing in case you don't know all the sizes from the start, essentially simulating the `ArrayList` functionality, but it might make sense if memory is an issue.

A `LinkedList` might be slightly preferable since you'd need to either make the array / `ArrayList` large enough to handle the maximum number of possible edges, or resize it as you go, where-as you don't have this problem with a `LinkedList`, but then again, creating the graph probably isn't the most resource-intensive task for most applications.

Bottom line - it's most likely going to make a negligible difference for most applications - just pick whichever one you feel most comfortable with (unless of course you need to do access-by-index a lot, or something which one of the two performs a lot better than the other).

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms 4th Edition by Sedgewick and Wayne proposes the following desired performance characteristics for a graph implementation that is useful for most graph-processing applications:

1. Space usage proportional to V + E
2. Constant time to add an edge
3. Time proportional to the degree of v to iterate through vertices adjacent to v (constant time per adjacent vertex processed)

Using a linked list to represent the vertices adjacent to each vertex has all these characteristics. Using an array instead of a linked list would result in either (1) or (2) not being achieved.

Comment: Lets say we maintain people & their connectivity degree in FaceBook..
I would prefer:
            class Graph{
       ArrayList<AdjacencyEntry> anAdjacencyList; 
      }
      class AdjacencyEntry { //its kind of HashMap(K,V) where K= aPerson , V = connections
       Node aPerson;
       ArrayList<Node> connections;
      }